# Dividing valuable items so that two persons get the most similar value possible

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

> You have n items, each one of those has a certain value, represented here as an integer.
>   How do you give to two persons the most similar value?

No comment from me here as my code already contains much documentation.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
import doctest

def all_subsets(lst):
    """
    Returns all the possibilities of taking n elements of the
    lst, where n goes from 0 to len(lst) - 1

    >>> list(all_subsets([1,2,3]))
    [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
    """
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(lst, i) for i in range(len(lst)))

def partitions(items):
    """
    All the possible ways to divide the items in two.

    >>> list(partitions([1,2,3]))
    [((1,), (2, 3)), ((2,), (1, 3)), ((3,), (1, 2)), ((1, 2), (3,)), ((1, 3), (2,)), ((2, 3), (1,))]
    """
    return ((a,b)
             for a in all_subsets(items)
               for b in all_subsets(items)
                 if set(a).union(set(b)) == set(items) and\
                    not set(a).intersection(set(b)))

def evenly_divide(items):
    """
    You have n items, each one of those has a certain value,
    represented here as an integer.

    How do you give to two persons the most similar value?

    This problem is NP-complete.
    This function finds the optimal solution by bruteforce.

    >>> evenly_divide( [1,2,3] )
    ((3,), (1, 2))
    >>> evenly_divide( [9, 12, 14, 17, 23, 32, 34, 40, 42, 49] )
    ((9, 12, 32, 34, 49), (14, 17, 23, 40, 42))
    """
    def difference(parts):
        first_part, second_part = parts
        return abs(sum(first_part) - sum(second_part))

    return min(partitions(items), key=difference)

def fevenly_divide(items):
    """
    You have n items, each one of those has a certain value,
    represented here as an integer.

    How do you give to two persons the most similar value?

    This problem is NP-complete.

    This function finds an approximate solution by sorting the items, and
    then giving the next item to the most poor guy.

    >>> fevenly_divide( [1,2,3] )
    ([2, 1], [3])
    >>> fevenly_divide( [9, 12, 14, 17, 23, 32, 34, 40, 42, 49] )
    ([42, 40, 32, 14, 9], [49, 34, 23, 17, 12])
    """
    first_guy = []
    second_guy = []
    for item in reversed(sorted(items)):
        if sum(first_guy) < sum(second_guy):
            first_guy.append(item)
        else:
            second_guy.append(item)
    return first_guy, second_guy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: There is an error in `fevenly_divide`.  The statement `first_guy = second_guy = []` makes first_guy and second_guy the same list.  If you run this function, you'll see both guys get all the numbers.  You need two separate initialization statements.

Comment: @saulspatz, I did not test after changing `first_guy = []; second_guy = []` to `first_guy = second_guy = []` as the change seemed so trivial.. yet it broke everything. I will edit in the fix in the anwwer to preserve on-topic-ness

Answer (score 1):

## partitions

This is inefficient since 
once you have one person's items you know what the other person's items are - just take the complement.

Also - does this condition really work if two items have the same value?

```
   if set(a).union(set(b)) == set(items) and\
        not set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

For instance, what if the values of the items are `[3,3,3,3]`?

This suggests that you should partition the item ids - not the item values.

Here is an example of what I'm getting at:

```
def evenly_divide(vals):
  ids = range(len(vals))
  total = sum(vals)
  half = total / 2

  bestSum = 0
  bestIds = []
  for a in all_subsets(ids):
    s = sum( vals[i] for i in a )
    if 2*s <= total and s > bestSum:
        bestSum = s
        bestIds = a
        if 2*s == total: break -- no need to continue
  return (bestSum, bestIds) # returns items for one person
```

This is still very inefficient, but it's more direct and concise.